# Cosine distance more than 1

Tags: python, scipy, cosine-similarity

I'm using the `distance.cosine` function from the `scipy.spatial` python package.
The problem is that my code returns me some values which are more than one.
How is that possible?

My code is very simple but that's it:

```
for i in range(len(vec.split(","))):
    w1=vec.split(",")[i]
    vec_1=embedding.get_phrase_vector(w1)/np.linalg.norm(embedding.get_phrase_vector(w1))
        for j in range(len(vec.split(","))):
            w2=vec.split(",")[j]
            vec_2=embedding.get_phrase_vector(w2)/np.linalg.norm(embedding.get_phrase_vector(w2))
            matrix[i][j]=distance.cosine(vec_1,vec_2)
```

the two vector giving me problems are:

```
w1=[-0.29137    1.0635    -0.41772    0.10439    0.46724    0.28249
 -0.04234   -0.07716    0.31482   -0.31903   -0.15905    0.98593
  0.40408   -0.33376    0.11372    0.3485     0.28884    0.082693
  0.86843   -0.40946   -0.64101   -0.55062    0.15105   -0.16613
  0.88421    0.31586    0.0017234 -0.46789   -0.48933   -0.38975
 -0.48061   -0.086691   0.96367    0.13027    0.10883    0.13111
 -0.28605    0.32731    0.10249   -0.50631   -0.27578    0.053391
  0.45665   -0.11782    0.039271   0.27073    0.46305    0.66542
 -0.41682   -0.14791   -0.9136    -0.71694   -0.11963    0.095209
  0.21016    0.67604   -0.23403   -0.39308    0.34853   -0.91753
  0.73017    0.79334   -0.25474    0.51577   -1.0458    -0.59653
 -0.54101   -0.056912   0.01262    0.046881   0.0708     0.20313
 -0.34206   -0.62316   -0.48464    0.013741   0.057855  -0.29289
 -0.1755     0.059357  -0.01446    0.17238    0.065214   0.4437
  0.38186   -0.21588    0.55824    0.099175  -0.0094545  0.82726
 -0.4048    -0.47035   -0.16345    0.080469  -0.048781   0.091551
  0.67828   -0.56955   -0.024643  -0.51526  ]
w2=[-1.6486e-01  9.1997e-01  2.2737e-01 -4.9031e-01 -1.8082e-03 -3.3803e-01
  5.7221e-02  1.4601e-01  4.0202e-01 -2.8858e-01 -4.7495e-01 -5.6369e-01
  2.7037e-01  5.1702e-01 -1.1241e-01  1.8314e-01  2.2066e-01 -4.8606e-01
 -8.7284e-01 -6.2587e-02  4.3016e-02  2.3641e-01  5.9705e-01 -3.8640e-01
 -2.5194e-01  9.6862e-01 -4.3112e-01 -4.8370e-01 -1.1396e+00  9.2425e-02
 -1.1476e-01 -7.4291e-02 -6.2524e-02 -9.5122e-02 -2.2714e-01  8.8291e-01
  3.9978e-01  7.6631e-01 -6.7697e-01 -6.2829e-01 -1.1872e-01 -2.4492e-01
 -5.8893e-01 -8.5088e-01  1.1107e+00  4.2190e-01 -1.5072e+00 -1.9509e-01
 -2.6712e-01 -7.0801e-01  5.5075e-01 -4.6929e-02 -2.5203e-01  7.4411e-01
 -1.8325e-01 -1.4885e+00 -4.6393e-01 -1.0338e-01  2.3525e+00 -1.5421e-01
  3.9833e-01  1.5344e-02  8.0708e-02 -2.7373e-01  9.7057e-01 -1.9383e-02
  2.0899e-01 -6.4033e-01  9.2509e-01 -4.5371e-01 -7.0564e-01 -1.6033e-01
 -7.1761e-02  6.2856e-01  3.5732e-01  8.8802e-01 -6.9127e-01  4.9634e-02
 -9.3347e-01  6.5396e-01  3.7165e-01  5.8363e-02 -1.0152e+00  7.0845e-01
 -1.3542e+00 -3.6390e-01  2.5994e-01 -1.8260e-01 -9.8930e-01 -4.4699e-01
  8.5016e-01  9.4532e-02  3.7019e-01 -5.0354e-01 -1.2083e+00 -3.5776e-01
  2.3899e-01 -6.7904e-02  1.5072e+00  6.0889e-01]
```

and their disctance results `1.08074426763993081`

Comment: For what vectors is this returning an invalid result? Please see [mre].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If dot product of these vectors is negative, it's perfectly OK for `cosine` to return a value greater than 1 (see the formula used for `cosine` in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html))

For example:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

cosine([1], [-1])
```

Output:

```
2.0
```